# I tried to solve string palindrome problem using stack and queues, but facing logical issues

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, queue

> Question: A palindrome is a string that reads the same forward and backward, for example, radar, toot, and madam. The challenge then is to write an algorithm that will read a sentence word-by-word from left to right and decide whether it is a palindrome.
>   Palindrome strings as an example.
>
> - “Madam, I’m Adam."
> - “Eve."
>
> The algorithm to solve this problem is relatively straightforward,
>
> - Use a stack and a queue.
> - Push and Enqueue tokens (words) into both data structures.
> - Pop and Dequeue the tokens (words) and compare.
> - Perform remove operation until one of the data structure is empty. If the case is that both are empty, the sentence is a palindrome.
>
> Your task is to figure out whether the string entered by the user is a palindrome or not.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stack>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 1000

class Stack
{
    int top;
public:
    string myStack[MAX];

    Stack() { top = -1; }
    bool push(string item)
    {
        if (top >= (MAX - 1)) {
            cout << "Stack is full";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            myStack[++top] = item;
            cout << item << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    string pop()
    {
        if (top < 0) {
            cout << "Stack Underflow!!";
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            string item = myStack[top--];
            return item;
        }
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
     if (top == -1)
         return true;
     else
         return false;

    }
};

class Queue
{ public:
    string myqueue[MAX];
    int front, rear;
    Queue()
    {
         front = -1;
        rear = -1;
    }
    bool isFull() {
        if (front == 0 && rear == MAX - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        if (front == -1) 
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    void enQueue(string item) {
        if (isFull()) {
            cout << endl << "Queue is full!!";
        }
        else {
            if (front == -1) front = 0;
            rear++;
            myqueue[rear] = item;
            cout << item << " "<<endl;
        }
    }
    string deQueue() {
        string value;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "Queue is empty!!" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            value = myqueue[front];
            if (front >= rear)
            {
                front = -1;
                rear = -1;
            }
            else {
                front++;
            }
            return(value);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    bool palindrome = true;
    Stack stack;
    stack.push("m");
    stack.push("a");
    stack.push("d");
    stack.push("a");
    stack.push("m");

    Queue queue;
    queue.enQueue("m");
    queue.enQueue("a");
    queue.enQueue("d");
    queue.enQueue("a");
    queue.enQueue("m");

    while (sizeof stack == 0 || sizeof queue == 0 )
    {
        stack.pop();
        queue.deQueue();
    };

    if (sizeof stack == sizeof queue )
    {
        cout << "The given word is palindrome." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The given word is not a palindrome." << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This exact same assignment was [asked about yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128070/) by another user. Must be class mates.

Comment: Please explain what concretely is not working and how you have tried to solve this.

Comment: I don't understand how can i pop and deque at the same time while comparing both the items from stack and queue.

Answer (score 1):

Ah the magic of `sizeof`.

`sizeof` has a very specific meaning (which you can look up). It does not magically get you the size of anything you like, defined in whatever way you prefer.

This code

```
while (sizeof stack == 0 || sizeof queue == 0 )
```

should be

```
while (stack.isEmpty() || queue.isEmpty())
```

You wrote your `isEmpty` methods, you should use them.

But even that code is wrong (because of logical issues). I guessing (but not really sure) that you meant

```
while (!stack.isEmpty() && !queue.isEmpty())
```

In short `sizeof` has no place in this code. If you need to know the size of your stacks or queues you should write a method (called `size` maybe) that returns the size.

Comment: Good Day, Sir @John. I am sure that everything you pointed out is correct. But i tried using isempty functions but they were not working properly. If you could please resolve this logical issue, it would be of great help to me, i have tried all methods that i could with my little knowledge and internet browsing, but i am unable to solve this problem.

Comment: @alizeykhan Look at your instructions. Pop and Dequeue the tokens (words) **and compare**. There's nothing in your code that compares the items being removed from the stack and the queue. If the two items removed are not equal then it's not a palindrome. I think the probem is that you don't understand the algorithm. Do you understand the algorithm? Until you understand the algorithm you can't write the code. Having said that although it's quite simple I don't think the algorithm has been very well described